# How to show that $\forall x\in \mathbb{R},\space \exists!n\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $n\leq x < n+1$?

Tags: real-analysis

How can I show that, $$\forall x\in \mathbb{R},\space \exists!n\in \mathbb{Z} \text{ such that, } \space n\leq x < n+1$$ which will be denoted later as $E(x)$ or $[x]$?

In my textbook the the prof prove it like that: Let $A = \{k\in \mathbb{Z},k\leq x \}$ $A$ is a non empty part of $\mathbb{Z}$ upper bounded (by x) in $\mathbb{R}$ so $A$ admits a largest element therefore $\exists!n\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that,  $n\leq x<n+1$ but I can't get this part

> therefore $\exists!n\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that,  $n\leq x<n+1$

Comment: You have a proof, then what suffers you?

Comment: i can't understand it

Comment: Explaining the points at which you have trouble understanding in the proof is what is needed in the question. It will greatly increase the chance to get an appropriate answer.

Comment: @sos440 are you suggesting that i should put the proof whit question?

Comment: Add the proof to the question (Edit-Button) and mark the steps you don't understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you agree with the existence of the largest element in $A$, the part of the proof in question follows as an easy consequence.

Let $n_0$ be the largest element in the set $A$. Then it satisfies the following properties:

1. $n_0 \leq x$, since $n_0$ is an element of $A$.
2. If $n < n_0$, then $n+1 \leq x$. This is clear from the inequality $n+1 \leq n_0 \leq x$.
3. If $n > n_0$, then $n > x$. Indeed, assume $n > n_0$. Then $n$ is not a member of $A$, otherwise the maximality of $n_0$ is contradicted. Since $n \notin A$, we have $n > x$.

Since $n_0 + 1 > n_0$, we have $n_0 \leq x < n_0 + 1$, which proves the *existence*. Also, both 2 and 3 excludes the possibility that $n \leq x < n+1$ is satisfied for some $n$ other than $n_0$. This proves the *uniqueness*.

If you are questioning the existence of the largest element of $A$, you may exploit the well-ordering principle of $\Bbb{N}$ with a slight modification.

Comment: Why he choose $A = \{k\in \mathbb{Z},k\leq x \}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $  Apply [continuous mathematical induction.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4424/242)

**Remark** $\ $ See the linked thread for various approaches to this sort of induction.

Answer (score 0):

What the proof says is that there is some set $A$, made of integer that are all less or equal to $x$. The set being bounded, it has a largest element, say $N$. In particular, $N\leq x$ by definition. Now why can we conclude that
$$
N\leq x<N+1?
$$

Suppose $x\geq N+1$, then certainly $N+1$ would be in our set $A$, which contradict the fact that $N$ was the maximal element. Therefore we conclude that $N\leq x<N+1$

Comment: Backwards.  This would be proved as a consequence of the result in the question.

Comment: it depends on how you see the problem, I agree that it does not go with the added information though

Comment: Downvote rescinded.  Another point (for the uniqueness): you need that there are no integers with distance less than 1 from each other.