# Induction over reals

Tags: induction

Would this argument be valid for proving A for all real numbers greater than or equal to a:

Prove that A is true at n = a.

Assume that A is true for all  $ a\le n < k$. Prove that A is true at k.

Comment: See Pete L. Clark's [nice introduction](http://math.uga.edu/~pete/realinduction.pdf) to real induction, which may have been sparked by by this prior question [Induction on real numbers.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4202/induction-on-real-numbers)

Comment: He wrote a slightly newer version [here](http://math.uga.edu/~pete/instructors_guide_shorter.pdf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, because your inductive step assumes that you know $A$ holds on some initial interval of the form $[a,k)$, but you have only shown that $A$ holds at a single initial point.

Comment: A single point is an interval: $[a,a]$.  Could you elaborate more?

Comment: Okay, I've clarified.

Comment: What if the "base case" is an interval?

Comment: Well if you show $A$ holds on the initial interval $[a,k)$, then show that $A$ holds on $[a,k)$ implies $A$ holds on $[a,k]$, you'll still only have shown that $A$ holds on $[a,k]$. I suggest you look at the links Dubuque posted to see how induction on the reals can work.