# Induction over real number

Tags: induction, real-numbers

I have to prove a property $P(x)$ hold for $\forall x: x \in (0,1]$. I also have a property $F\big(\frac{x}2\big)=F(x)+1$ which is key to prove $P(x)$. If I prove following steps:

1. $P(x-\epsilon)$ holds for $\forall \epsilon$,where $\frac{x}{2}<x-\epsilon<x$
2. $P\big(\frac{x}{2}\big)$ holds
3. $\forall x \in (0,1],\space \space \exists \frac{x}{2} \in (0,1]$.

It this a correct way to prove using induction over real number?

Comment: I guess that's $\forall \epsilon \dots$ ?

Comment: yes thanks a lot..i have update the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not the only one asking this question. Pete Clark has given it a lot of thought and gives a good answer in [this discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4202/induction-on-real-numbers).

Comment: [Slightly relevant](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~wtg10/ordinals.html) (uses transfinite induction to prove a property on $(0,1)$)