# Help required to prove the following inequality...

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Our professor wrote this problem on board and left the room stating, "Try it if you want. You'll succeed only if have properly gone through the concepts that were taught last week."

Let $f :[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous on $[0,1]$ and differentiable in $(0,1)$. If $f(0)=0$ and $f'(x) \geq f(x)$ $\forall$ $x \in [0,1],$ prove that $f(x) \geq 0$ $\forall$ $x \in [0,1].$

I tried solving the above problem using mean value theorems, but unfortunately it didn't work. Some suggestions or solutions of this problem will be really helpful.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Multiply by $e^{-x}$ on both sides.

Comment: I had gone the MVT way, but not successful.

Comment: @Mark, I went that way thinking the problem can be easily tackled... but alas. May be we sometimes cannot see things that are too close to our eyes. Can you help a bit?

Comment: @PriyadarshiMukherjee Read Gabriel's comment. Try that, reorganize the inequality, and recognize a derivative.

Comment: @Gabriel, can you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: Sorry, I thought for a moment that you have $f'(x)\geq 0$. But it is actually $f'(x)\geq f(x)$ so MVT will not be so easy. Anyway, Gabriel Romon already gave a hint.

Comment: I don’t know who down voted. But doing it without an explanation seems very unproductive to me.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Because literally this question shows no personal work, which is a clear thing in the website policy (which I assume you know?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be differentiable such that $f(0)=0$ and $f'(x)>f(x),\forall x \in \mathbb R$ ; then is $f(x)>0,\forall x>0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1576874/f-mathbb-r-to-mathbb-r-be-differentiable-such-that-f0-0-and-fxfx)

Comment: @ClementC. Yes I know. However I wouldn’t down vote. Recalling the policy looks enough to me. A question of feeling at the end!

Comment: Well, I voted to close, not downvoted. In the end, it's indeed a matter of feeling.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is only fair to note that our OP's assertion that $f'(x) \ge f(x), \; \forall x \in [0, 1]$ tacitly implies $f(x)$ is in fact differentiable on $[0, 1]$.  Hence:

For all $x \in [0, 1]$ we have

$f'(x) \ge f(x), \tag 0$

whence

$f'(x) - f(x) \ge 0, \; \forall x \in [0, 1]; \tag 1$

now since $e^{-x} > 0$,

$e^{-x}f'(x) - e^{-x}f(x) \ge 0; \tag 2$

that is,

$(e^{-x}f(x))' \ge 0; \tag 3$

thus, with $f(0) = 0$,

$e^{-x}f(x) = e^{-x}f(x) - e^0 f(0) = \displaystyle \int_0^x (e^{-s}f(s))' \; ds \ge 0; \tag 4$

finally, multiply by $e^x$:

$f(x) \ge 0. \tag 5$

Comment: Thank you very much @Robert

Comment: @PriyadarshiMukherjee:  my pleasure good sir!