# simple induction related question where we are doing it for k ∈ R

Tags: induction

suppose we want to prove by induction that
$$1^2+ 
2^2+ 
3^2+ 
4^2+ ....... + n^2= \frac{n}{6}(n+1)(2n+1)$$
it is very easy where we assume $k$ and $k+1$.

suppose we want to prove $$3^k>2^k, \forall k\in\mathbb R^+$$

then while doing induction (if we are allowed to), can we assume for any general $k$ and instead of proving it for $k+1$, are we allowed to do it for limit as $h$ tends to zero $k+h$ ?

Comment: This is not clear.  You generally can't do induction in $\mathbb R$.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Induction works when $k \in \mathbb{N}$, not for  $k \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: For this particular problem, I'd look at the function $f(x)=\left(\frac 32\right)^x$ and note that $f(0)=1$ but $f'(x)$ is strictly positive.

Comment: guys, i know how to solve the problem. my doubt is why the limit doesnt work.
k and k+1 work well but why dont k and k+h work

Answer (score 0):

The proof technique of induction is usually only used for natural numbers (0 inclusive). So I think you would be better off with a deductive proof rather than doing it by induction.

Check out [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1588666/why-do-we-do-mathematical-induction-only-for-positive-whole-numbers/1588698) for more about why.

Comment: dj im not trying to solve my problem. look into the comment i made above