# Can I extend mathematical induction to real numbers?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, real-numbers

Here is my rather simple idea. I will treat the set of real numbers as a set of discrete continuities, each separated by an Epsilon ball that tends to 0.

So, let's say P(b) is true.
We then assume P(k) is true, and prove that P(k+e) is true, where e goes to zero.

I just want to know if this is a valid technique or not because our teacher said that mathematical induction can only be applied to discrete structures, but I see no difficulty in treating a continuous system as a set of infinitesimal discrete quantities. Mak

Comment: Google 'real induction'. There are notes by Pete Clark.

Comment: then you will never reach to P(b+1) for example. Actually, you just have fun around epsilon neighborhood around b, which(epsilon) by the way tends to 0.

Comment: Wow I have never heard about that! Thanks @PedroTamaroff

Comment: By the way, you should work a bit on your exposition. For example, you wrote: "*So, let's say P(b) is true. We then assume P(k) is true, and prove that P(k+e) is true, where e goes to zero*"... And then **what**? What is it that you're trying to prove? That $P(x)$ holds for every real number $x$, for example? Also, "*prove that P(k+e) is true, where e goes to zero*" is too vague to be useful: what do you mean by that, precisely?

Comment: The approach to real induction explained in the paper attached to [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/4424/65389) by Bill Dubuque is most similar to what you're hinting at here. I'm voting to close this question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

This seems unlikely, since there are plenty of bounded subsets of the real line having no maximum or minimum element. The natural numbers are well-ordered; this is induction. The reals are not.