# A segment can be divided with consecutive points in the same closed subset.

Tags: calculus, general-topology, multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis

> Prove that a segment in a convex closed set covered by closed subsets
>   can be divided in a way that consecutive points lie in the same
>   closed set.

Suppose tat $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ is a convex and closed set such that $D = \cup_{i = 1}^n C_i$ with $C_i$ closed. I need to show that for a segment $[x,y] \subseteq D$ I can give a partition with points $t_i$ such that $t_i,t_{i+1}$lie in the same $C_j$ for all $i$ (so $t_1,t_2$ lie in $C_1$,$t_2,t_3$ lie in $C_j'$...)

**My problem**

With different ideas I can start with $x \in C_1$ and get a point at the frontier $Fr(C_1)$. The problem is now how to prove that points in the frontier must be shared with another $C_i$.

Another way would be to take the maximum of $\alpha^{-1}$ ($\alpha(t) = tx+(1-t)y$) in $C_1$ and realize that $\alpha(t_{\max}+ \frac 1 n)$ lies in another $C_i$ and take limits but potential each $n$ cou.d lie in a different $C_{i_n}$

Comment: What is a consequitive point?  How is D ordered?

Comment: @WilliamElliot consecutive = successive (in the partition), D is not ordered is a domain...

Comment: How is [x,y] a segment of the plain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly the proposition holds for $[x,x]$.

Assume that the proposition holds for $[x,z]\subset [x,y]$. This is, there are $x=t_1<t_2<...<t_n=z$ (the order being the linear order induced by $(1-t)x+ty$ from $[0,1]$) such that consecutive $t_i$ lie in a common $C_i$.

If $z<y$, then there is a sequence $z_1>z_2>z_3>...>z$ of points in $(z,y]$  such that $z_i\to z$. There is some $C_{i_0}$ such that infinitely many elements of this sequence lie in it. After all, the whole sequence is included in $\bigcup_{i=1}^n C_i$. So, at least one of them contains infinitely many elements of the sequence. Therefore $z\in C_{i_0}$. Take $t_{n+1}=sup_{u\in[x,y]\cap C_{i_0}}(u)$. Observe that $t_{n+1}\neq t_n$ because $C_{i_0}$ contains points of $(z,y]$. Also $t_{n+1}\in C_{i_0}$. Therefore, the proposition holds for $[x,z]$ for $z>y$.

By continuous induction the proposition holds for $[x,y]$. If uncomfortable with continuous induction, let $z$ in the paragraph above, the largest such that the proposition holds. If $z<y$ you get a contradiction by finding a larger point in which it also holds. Therefore, the maximum is $y$.

Comment: What is *continuous induction*? Links and references please.

Comment: @Javier You can start from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4204/550675), or [here](http://math.uga.edu/~pete/realinduction.pdf) and references therein.

Comment: @max_zorn See previous comment.