# Proof by induction on an uncountable interval

Tags: proof-writing, induction

I'm a little bit confused as to whether or not I can use proof by induction on an uncountable interval.  For example, I'm trying to prove that $$(x+y)^n \leq x^n + y^n$$ on the interval $0 \leq n \leq 1$.

Primarily, I'm stuck on what my base case would be.  Just n = 0?

Comment: Induction on an uncountable interval is a different logical beast than ordinary induction.  For instance, the interval $0 \leq n \leq 1$ does not satisfy the Well-Ordering Principle.  So induction is probably not the intended answer here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove, by induction, $x\ne 1\implies x+1\ne2$ for all $x$ in $[0,1]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2914942/prove-by-induction-x-ne-1-implies-x1-ne2-for-all-x-in-0-1)

Comment: The "duplicate" is about the general case of "induction over an interval" and more, it will help the confusion but not specifically about this case

Comment: Maybe you could try to do induction for a countable subset of the interval, and see how the two sides behave when you put $n$ tends to an irrational... To do that you might want the subset to be dense possibly. I have not tried myself, so the above is pure guessing.

Comment: Yes, the base case is $n=0$.