# show that for $a \ge 2, n \ge a, (1 + \frac{1}{(n-a+1)/(a-1)})^{(n-a+1)/(a-1)} < e$

Tags: inequality, induction, exponential-function

In the [proof](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/267137759_On_the_product_of_the_primes) by Denis Hanson (see Lemma 3), this is presented as obvious if $a \ge 2$ and $n > a$:

$$\left(1 + \dfrac{1}{(n-a+1)/(a-1)}\right)^{(n-a+1)/(a-1)} < e$$

where $e$ is [Euler's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)) which is approximately $2.72$

For me, this is not obvious so I thought I would detail the argument for why this is true.

Here's what I came up with (I understand that induction can be used for real numbers [under certain circumstances](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4204/48606)):

- Let $u = (n-a+1)/(a-1)$
- **Base Case**:  for $n=a$, then $u = \dfrac{1}{a-1}$

$\left(1 + \dfrac{1}{u}\right)^u = a^{\frac{1}{a-1}} < 2 < e$ since $\dfrac{\log a}{\log 2} \le a-1 $

- **Inductive Hypothesis**: up to some $u \ge \dfrac{1}{a-1}$:
  $$\left(1 + \dfrac{1}{u}\right)^{u} < e$$
- **Inductive case**: For $\epsilon > 0$:

$\dfrac{u+1}{u} > \dfrac{u+1+\epsilon}{u+\epsilon}$ since $(u+1)(u+\epsilon) = u^2 + u + u\epsilon + \epsilon > u^2 + u + u\epsilon = (u)(u+1+\epsilon)$

$\left(\dfrac{u+1}{u}\right)^u > \left(\dfrac{u+\epsilon+1}{u+\epsilon}\right)^u$

$\left(\dfrac{u+\epsilon+1}{u+\epsilon}\right)^{\epsilon} < 1$

Which gives us that:

$$\left(1 + \dfrac{1}{u+\epsilon}\right)^{u+\epsilon}< \left(1+\dfrac{1}{u}\right)^{u} < e$$

Is this argument valid?  Is there a simpler way to establish Hanson's step?

Comment: What denotes $e$ here?

Comment: $e$ is Euler’s constant ~ 2.72....  I’ll update the question to add this detail.

Comment: Put $t = (a-1)/(n+ a -1) \in (0,1)$. The estimate is equivalent to $(1+t)^{1/t} < e$ or $\ln(1+t) < t$. The function $f(t) = \ln(1+t) -t$ satisfies $f(0) = 0$ and $f'(t) = -t/(1+t) < 0$. Therefore $f(t) < f(0) =0$ for $t >0$.

Comment: Thanks!  If you put that as the answer, I will be glad to accept.

Comment: In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/306245) it is shown that $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$ is increasing and $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n+1}$ is decreasing.

Comment: @LarryFreeman: Ok, I put it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put $t = (a-1)/(n+a -1) \in (0,1)$. The estimate is equivalent to $(1+ t)^{1/t} < e$ or $\ln(1+t) < t$. Consider the function $f(t) = \ln(1+t) -t, t >0$. We have $f(0) =0$ and 
$$f'(t) = \frac1{1+t} -1 = -\frac{t}{t+1} < 0, \, t >0.$$
Therefore, $f(t) < f(0) =0$ for $t>0$, or equivalently, $\ln(1+t) < t$ for $t >0$.