# Confusion with the Taylor theorem for vetor-valued multivariable functions

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a smooth function.

If I pick a point $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then I think I can apply the Taylor theorem to $f$ by
\begin{equation}
f(x)=f(a)+[Df(a)] \cdot (x-a) + \text{remainder } R_1(x,a)
\end{equation}
where $Df(a)$ is the Jacobian matrix of $f$ at $a$ and $[Df(a)] \cdot (x-a)$ means that $ n\times n$ matrix is multiplied to $n \times 1$ column vector. Also, $R_1(x,a)$ is $\mathbb{R}^n$-valued smooth function of $x$ for the given $a$,

Now, if I write like this, I wonder if
\begin{equation}
\frac{\lVert R_1(x,a) \rVert}{\lVert x-a \rVert^2}
\end{equation}
is bounded as $x \to a$.

Generalizing from one dimensions, I guess this must be true, but I am extremely confused due to many variables interwined..

Could anyone please clarify?

Comment: If you assume $f$ is smooth (weaker conditions suffice) then sure it is true. There are several statements for Taylor’s theorem in the Banach-space setting, and bounds on the remainder, see eg [Bound on remainder for vector valued Taylor series](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3479165/568204). For a more detailed explanation, I suggest reading Henri Cartan’s text.

Comment: Generally the remainder is $o(\| x-a \|)$, not $o(\| x-a \|^2)$.